# Sharding in mongodb with c# for getting the records as required

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver, sharding

I have 2 millions of data in some csv files...
I am getting those files and reducing it to get result sumthing like this.,..

```
{ "_id" : "08-08-2012 05:00", "value" : { "CollectionDate" : "08-08-2012 05:00", "count" : 20000 } }
{ "_id" : "08-08-2012 05:15", "value" : { "CollectionDate" : "08-08-2012 05:15", "count" : 20000 } }
{ "_id" : "08-08-2012 05:30", "value" : { "CollectionDate" : "08-08-2012 05:30", "count" : 20000 } }
{ "_id" : "08-08-2012 05:45", "value" : { "CollectionDate" : "08-08-2012 05:45", "count" : 20000 } }
{ "_id" : "08-08-2012 06:00", "value" : { "CollectionDate" : "08-08-2012 06:00", "count" : 20001 } }
{ "_id" : "08-08-2012 06:15", "value" : { "CollectionDate" : "08-08-2012 06:15", "count" : 20000 } }
{ "_id" : "08-08-2012 06:30", "value" : { "CollectionDate" : "08-08-2012 06:30", "count" : 20000 } }
....
{ "_id" : "08-08-2012 10:30", "value" : { "CollectionDate" : "08-08-2012 06:30", "count" : 20000 } }
{ "_id" : "08-08-2012 10:45", "value" : { "CollectionDate" : "08-08-2012 06:30", "count" : 20000 } }
{ "_id" : "08-08-2012 11:00", "value" : { "CollectionDate" : "08-08-2012 06:30", "count" : 20000 } }
```

Source code for getting this result is as:

```
class DirectImport
{
    private static bool forOnce = true;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
        bool reset = true;
        BsonString lastAggregatedDate = "";
        String lastCollName = "";
        MongoServer mongo = MongoServer.Create();
        mongo.Connect();
        Console.WriteLine("Connected"); Console.WriteLine();
        var db = mongo.GetDatabase("SampleData");
        using (mongo.RequestStart(db))
        {
            List<BsonDocument> mDoc = new List<BsonDocument>();
            IEnumerable<String> CollectionList = Directory.EnumerateFiles(@"c:\mongoDb\Final");
            DateTime oldDt = new DateTime(1, 1, 1);
            foreach (String coll in CollectionList.ToArray<String>())
            {
                String collName = coll.Substring(coll.LastIndexOf(@"\") + 1);
                collName = collName.Substring(0, collName.LastIndexOf('.'));
                //Console.WriteLine(collName);
                string[] records = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\mongoDB\Final\" + collName + ".csv");
                mDoc = new List<BsonDocument>();

                var newCollection = db.GetCollection<BsonDocument>(collName);
                for (int l = 1; l < records.Length; l++)
                {
                    string[] abc = records[l].Split(',');
                    //Console.WriteLine(abc[1] + "_" + abc[2] + "_" + abc[5]);
                    BsonDocument book1 = new BsonDocument();
                    book1.Add("_id", BsonString.Create(abc[1] + "_" + abc[2] + "_" + abc[5]));
                    book1.Add("Base_Name", BsonString.Create(abc[0]));
                    book1.Add("ObjectType", BsonString.Create(abc[1]));
                    book1.Add("C_ID", BsonString.Create(abc[2]));
                    book1.Add("AssociateDimension1", BsonString.Create(abc[3]));
                    book1.Add("AssociateDimension2", BsonInt32.Create(abc[4]));
                    book1.Add("CollectionDateHour", BsonInt32.Create(Convert.ToDateTime(BsonString.Create(abc[5])).Hour));
                    book1.Add("CollectionDate", BsonString.Create(abc[5]));
                    book1.Add("Granularity", BsonInt32.Create(abc[6]));
                    book1.Add("Counter1_1", BsonDouble.Create(abc[7]));
                    book1.Add("Counter1_2", BsonDouble.Create(abc[8]));
                    book1.Add("Counter1_3", BsonDouble.Create(abc[9]));
                    book1.Add("Counter1_4", BsonDouble.Create(abc[10]));
                    book1.Add("Counter1_5", BsonDouble.Create(abc[11]));
                    book1.Add("Counter1_6", BsonDouble.Create(abc[12]));
                    book1.Add("Counter1_7", BsonDouble.Create(abc[13]));
                    if (forOnce)
                    {
                        forOnce = false;
                        oldDt = Convert.ToDateTime(BsonString.Create(abc[5]));
                        lastCollName = collName;
                    }
                    DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(BsonString.Create(abc[5]));
                    mDoc.Add(book1);
                    newCollection.Insert(book1);
                    String[] strparam = { "CollectionDate" };
                    if (!newCollection.IndexExists(strparam))
                        newCollection.CreateIndex(strparam);
                    if (oldDt > dt)
                        Console.WriteLine(dt + ":::" + oldDt);
                    if (((dt - oldDt).Hours >= 1) || oldDt > dt)
                    {
                        stopwatch.Start();
                        Console.WriteLine("Calling MAPReduce at: " + oldDt);
                        Console.WriteLine();
                        //var coll1 = db.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("MSS1");
                        //coll1.InsertBatch<BsonDocument>(mDoc);
                        MapReduce(db, lastCollName, dt, lastAggregatedDate, reset);
                        lastCollName = collName;
                        //coll1.Drop();
                        lastAggregatedDate = BsonString.Create(abc[5]);
                        reset = false;
                        mDoc = new List<BsonDocument>();
                        oldDt = dt;
                        TimeSpan ts = stopwatch.Elapsed;
                        Console.WriteLine("RunTime: " + ts.Hours + ":" + ts.Minutes + ":" + ts.Seconds + ":" + ts.Milliseconds / 10);
                        stopwatch.Stop();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        Console.Read();
        mongo.Disconnect();
    }
private static void MapReduce(MongoDatabase db, String collName, BsonValue bsonValue, BsonString lastAggregateDate, bool reset)
    {
        var collection = db.GetCollection<BsonDocument>(collName);
        Console.WriteLine(collName);
        String map = @"function() { 
                                    emit(this.CollectionDate, {CollectionDate : this.CollectionDate, count: 1});
                                  }";
        String reduce = @"function(key, values) {
                                        var result = {CollectionDate:key, count: 0};
                                        values.forEach(function(value){
                                            result.count += value.count;
                                        });
                                        return result;
                                    }";
        var options = new MapReduceOptionsBuilder();
        IMongoQuery[] queries = { Query.GTE("CollectionDate", lastAggregateDate) };
        //if(reset)
        //    queries = new IMongoQuery[] { Query.LT("CollectionDate", bsonValue) };

        options.SetOutput(MapReduceOutput.Reduce("MSS_REDUCE"));
        //options.SetOutput(MapReduceOutput.Reduce);
        IMongoQuery query = Query.And(queries);
        var results = collection.MapReduce(queries[0], map, reduce, options);
}
```

Now the problem is that my required output is :

```
{ "_id" : "08-08-2012 05:00", "value" : { "CollectionDate" : "08-08-2012 05:00", "count" : 20000 } }
{ "_id" : "08-08-2012 06:00", "value" : { "collectionDate" : "08-08-2012 06:00", "count" : 80000 } }
{ "_id" : "08-08-2012 07:00", "value" : { "collectionDate" : "08-08-2012 07:00", "count" : 80000 } }
{ "_id" : "08-08-2012 08:00", "value" : { "CollectionDate" : "08-08-2012 07:45", "count" : 80000 } }
{ "_id" : "08-08-2012 09:00", "value" : { "collectionDate" : "08-08-2012 09:00", "count" : 80000 } }
{ "_id" : "08-08-2012 10:00", "value" : { "collectionDate" : "08-08-2012 10:00", "count" : 80000 } }
{ "_id" : "08-08-2012 11:00", "value" : { "CollectionDate" : "08-08-2012 10:45", "count" : 80000 } }
```

Now I think it can be done by sharding on _id key.. but how to do this in c# and how to achieve this result..
Please help me

Comment: And if its not sharding.. then also tell me the way through which I can get the same output as I need.. Thanks in advance..

Comment: what version of mongodb are you running?

Comment: I'm not sure I can see what you are asking, but I think it is not to do with sharding.  Are you trying to get the mapreduce to give the results given in your final example?  If so, what is the distinction between `5:00` and `7:00` such that the `5:00` group does not have a `5:45` while the `7:00` group does?

Comment: actually all the data between 5:15 to 6:00 comes under 6:00

Comment: This sounds a lot more like a problem with the map reduce, but I'm still not clear on the requirements.  Why is there a `7:45` and a `10:45` grouping?

Comment: ok let 7:45 and 10:45 be 8:00 and 11:00 first.. solve like this first.. please..

Answer (score 2):

This question can be solved by altering your map reduce, unless I am mistaken.

My assumption from the comments is that what you are looking for is a sum of each hour, for each previous hour.  This means that you can mapreduce on the `CollectionDateHour` rather than the `CollectionDate`.  You can then control in the application where you want the `CollectionDateHour` to fall (for example you can decide if `6:45` is in the `7:00` group or in the `6:00` group.

There is two points to change in your application, first handle the collection date hour:

```
for (int l = 1; l < records.Length; l++)
{
...
    var collectionDate = Convert.ToDateTime(BsonString.Create(abc[5]));
    var collectionDateHour = collectionDate.Minute>0?collectionDate.AddHours(1).Hour:collectionDate.Hour;
    book1.Add("CollectionDateHour", BsonInt32.Create(collectionDateHour));
...
```

Which is simply making the `CollectionDateHour` one more than the hour from `CollectionDate` if there is any minute part of `CollectionDate`.  You can tune this to fit your logic.

The second change is to adjust your map reduce function so that you are reducing based on the `CollectionDateHour` rather than the full string you have used previously.  One way to do this would be to change your map function:

```
String map = @"function() { 
    var newCollectionDate = this.CollectionDate.split(' ')[0] + (this.CollectionDateHour<10?' 0':' ')+this.CollectionDateHour + ':00'
    emit(newCollectionDate, {CollectionDate : newCollectionDate, count: 1});
}";
```

Which will set the collection date to the hour figure worked out in your application logic and and reduce on that.  Given the above two changes, the following input:

```
{ "CollectionDate" : "08-08-2012 05:00" }
{ "CollectionDate" : "08-08-2012 05:15" }
{ "CollectionDate" : "08-08-2012 05:10" }
{ "CollectionDate" : "08-08-2012 04:00" }
{ "CollectionDate" : "08-08-2012 12:45" }
{ "CollectionDate" : "08-08-2012 12:46" }
{ "CollectionDate" : "08-08-2012 23:45" }
```

Will give these results:

```
{ "_id" : "08-08-2012 00:00", "value" : { "CollectionDate" : "08-08-2012 00:00", "count" : 1 } }
{ "_id" : "08-08-2012 04:00", "value" : { "CollectionDate" : "08-08-2012 04:00", "count" : 1 } }
{ "_id" : "08-08-2012 05:00", "value" : { "CollectionDate" : "08-08-2012 05:00", "count" : 1 } }
{ "_id" : "08-08-2012 06:00", "value" : { "CollectionDate" : "08-08-2012 06:00", "count" : 2 } }
{ "_id" : "08-08-2012 13:00", "value" : { "CollectionDate" : "08-08-2012 13:00", "count" : 2 } }
```